# Javascript - Passing a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Apologies, I could not find a solution that worked, despite similar questions being asked and answered.

I have a modal which is opened with openModal() which has a close button in the top-right corner. When I click close, I'd like a function to run depending on the argument which has been passed.

```
function openModal(onclose){
    //insert modal
    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    body.appendChild(modal);

    //insert close button
    var modalClose = document.createElement('span');
    modalClose.innerHTML = '&Chi;'
    modalClose.classList.add('modalClose');
    modal.appendChild(modalClose);

    //call default function on click of close button
    modalClose.addEventListener("click", closeModal);


    //call custom function on click of close button
    if(beforeclose !== undefined){
        modalClose.addEventListener("click", onclose);
}
```

I would then call something like openModal('refreshPage()') where refreshPage would only run on the click of the close button.

Thanks for any help you can offer me - i should say I have tried to use eval in the addeventlistener and it just ran it immediately and then also when the button was clicked.

Comment: Why it's `onclose` in the argument, and `onClose` later? JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: uhm... in `openModal('refreshPage()')`, `'refreshPage()'` is a string, not a function, and if you removed the quotes, it would call the function immediately due to the `()`.

Comment: @raina77ow , just a mistake, I changed my actual code for clarity - I guess that didnt work so well.

Comment: Then follow @KevinB advice - pass function as function, not as string.

Answer (score 0):

Do `element.addEventListener(onclose, function(){ closeModal(refreshPage); });`.

Then you can design your `closeModal` function like this:

```
function closeModal(func){
   func();
}
```

References to functions are in the form of variables without the `()`:

- `function foo()` is referenced via `foo`
- `function getData()` is referenced via `getData`
- `function bar(); const barr = bar` is referenced via `bar` or `barr`